# How to select a value from dropdown menu in Jest unit test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, drop-down-menu

```
  return (
    <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={localizedMessages}>
      <LocaleContext.Provider value={locale}>
        {showLocaleSelector && (
          <FormControl className="locale-dropdown">
            <InputLabel id="locale-label">Language</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="locale-label"
              value={locale}
              label="Language"
              onChange={handleChange}
              defaultValue={LOCALE}
            >
              {supportedLocales.map((item) => {
                const { key, value } = item;

                return (
                  <MenuItem value={key} key={key}>
                    {value}
                  </MenuItem>
                );
              })}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        )}
        {props.children}
      </LocaleContext.Provider>
    </IntlProvider>
  );
```

in the above mentioned code block.i was trying to test whether the page re-render when user selects prefered language from the dropdown menu.please help to to create a unit test to check whether the page re render with selected language by the user from the dropdown menu